# Celery chords - how to get results of partially successful header?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Django app that pushes config to network devices using netmiko. To do that I use a Celery task to do the actual work, do any retries as necessary and update some Django model instances with the task's progress. Then there's a view that shows the user the current state of those tasks. Tasks come in sets (one change => several devices), so I'd like to report at the change level on their success - sometimes one device won't respond but most others will.

I thought I could use chords in Celery to do this, and got as far as:

```
for d in devices:
    pd = DeviceConfigPush(d.task_info)
    subtasks.append(pd.s(task_info))

master = MasterConfigPush()
ch = chord(header=subtasks, body=master.s().set(link_error=['push_ssh_task_master']))
ch.delay()
```

which works, but the master task (the body of the chord) gets called with either a list of the results if they were all successful, or a UUID if any failed. I was hoping to get something like ['result', 'result', None, 'result']. I also can't see anything in Flower that matches the UUID passed in the fail situation.

So:
1) What is the significance of the UUID?
2) How can the body task access the results of the header tasks, regardless?

Comment: Perhaps you could try to capture when master fails and return None yourself? Also, isn't the chord form [`result = chord(header)(callback)`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords)?

Comment: Actually, have you had a look at [`chord Error handling`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#error-handling)?